# Add row into many to many relationship table after row creation with Talend

Tags: many-to-many, talend, data-integration

I am using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration to create a job that's supposed to do the following:

1. Get a row from table1
2. If a row with a certain value doesn't exist in table 2: add a row into table2
3. add a row into a many-to-many relationship table using id from table1's row and id from table2's (existing or newly created) row

for example, let's say i have the tables PROFILE, USER and REL_PROFILES_USERS, i need to populate USER starting from PROFILE and every PROFILE row with the same name will be associated to the same USER

so i start with the PROFILE table

```
 id |  name  | address  
-----------------------------------
  1 | jsmith | 1234 Main Street  
  2 | jasonp | 321 Secondary Street  
  3 | jsmith | NULL
```

and i want to end up with USER popuplated this way

```
 id |  username
----------------
  1 | jsmith 
  2 | jasonp
```

and REL_PROFILES_USERS

```
 user |  profile
----------------
  1   |    1 
  1   |    3
  2   |    2
```

I have managed to make point 1. and 2. with a simple tMap between `PROFILE` and `USER` and i am populating `REL_PROFILES_USERS` after the first `tMap` using a separate subjob with a `tMap` and a inner join on all matches between `USER` and `PROFILE` on `PROFILE.name = USER.username`.

What i'd like to do is to populate REL_PROFILE_USERS in the same subjob where i populate USER, soon after the new row has been inserted or when you see there's an already existing row, without knowing about the relationship between USER and PROFILE (that username = name) but only because i'm working on those rows

Comment: So how does your job look like?

Comment: Do it in 2 passes. 1st pass filter out the distinct users from your flow. Then join that with the target table. In tMap catch inner join reject -> you have the users that are missing from your table. Add these users to your table. Second pass, join the users table with your input flow.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you didn't state which database you're using, so I'm going to assume MS SQL for purposes of discussion Talend has equivalent database components for the major databases, plus generic JDBC for anything else.

I suggest trying this flow

tMSSqlInput (from profile) -> [tMSSqlOutput](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tMSSqlOutput) (on user) -> [tMSSqlLastInsertId](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tMSSqlLastInsertId) (to get the inserted id) -> tMSSqlOutput  (on ref_profiles_user)

Alternatively,  you could turn on identity insert in tMsSqlOutput, on the first insert.That way you know the PK of row inserted into the user table.Then you can can  proceed to insert into the rel_users_profile table. I recommend against generating your own PK for the 1st table unless this is the only process which inserts records into this table. Calling a sequence in the database to get the next sequence number is a bit safer than generating your own seq.

tMSSqlInput (from profile) -> (generate ID perhaps by calling get next sequence or generate your own in tMap) -> tMSSqlOutput (on user) -> tMSSqlOutput  (on ref_profiles_user)

Have fun and good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i am wondering how to get profile_id though. You guessed correctly about the DB, it's MS SQL

Comment: You get the profile_id in the first tMsSqlInput, using a query like "SELECT id, name, address FROM profile"

Comment: See updated table names in the example flow to match your scenario.